# Are all these pairs of primes twin primes?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, twin-primes

For $a$ and $b$ primes, if both $(a^b \bmod b)$ and $(b^a \bmod a)$ are prime,
does this imply that $(a,b)$ are twin primes?

For example, for $(a,b)=(41,43)$, $(41^{43} \bmod 43) = 41$ and $(43^{41} \bmod 41) = 2$.

Whereas for $(a,b)=(41,47)$, $(41^{47} \bmod 47) = 41$
but $(47^{41} \bmod 41) = 6$, not a prime.

Comment: "Primes" doesn't make much sense when talking modular arithmetic. For instance, modulo $41$, you _only_ get information about modulo $41$, and a prime could be anything (except $0$). In fact, it's been proven that over time, each congruency classes has roughly the same number of primes as any other.

Comment: @Arthur, I tale the $x\bmod y$ notation to mean that one is taking the smallest non-negative residue of $x$ modulo $y$. Then "prime" makes perfect sense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, you're right. But it still rarely means anything. The only thing that means something is coprime to $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $3^{11} \bmod 11 = 3$, and $11^3 \bmod 3 = 2$, but $3$ and $11$ are not twin primes.

$(5,13)$ also works, and both of the other primes constructed in this case are odd.

Comment: as well as (41,101) etc. all it means is that the difference between them is a  prime mod the lower. the first way hold for any prime pair due to fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 1):

No, the implication here is that b has a prime remainder when dividing by a, or a has a prime remainder when dividing by b. nothing more. you can see this applying Fermat's little theorem:

$a^{b-1}\equiv 1 \bmod b$ when a and b are coprime ( aka gcd(a,b)==1).

applying the more accurate version we get $a^b\equiv a \bmod b$ if a is prime we have a prime remainder, same ( but different possibly) going the other way: $b^a\equiv b \bmod a$  but one of a or b must be greater which then reduces to a prime so this happens any time either $a \bmod b$ or $b \bmod a$ depending on which is greater, are prime.